# python tkinter - adding values from treeview column

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have treeview in my GUI(n=rows, 3 columns). Rows keep adding as the user enters values in a label and presses a button. Lets assume the user has entered 3 values i.e 3 rows get inserted into my treeview. Now, I would like to add up the values in one of the column and display it in another label. How can i do it?

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    self.entry=ttk.Entry(self,width=10,)
    self.entry.grid(row=2, column=2, ) #value entered by the user and displayed in Temp column
    self.entry1=ttk.Entry(self,width=10,)
    self.entry1.grid(row=2, column=3, )#value entered by the user and displayed in time column
    ttk.Button(self, text='Enter', command=self.insert_data).grid(row=2,column=4, )#calling the method insert data to insert the values entered by the user
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview( self, columns=('Temp','time'))
    self.tree.heading('#0', text='Number')
    self.tree.heading('#1', text='Temp')
    self.tree.heading('#2', text='time')
    self.tree.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES)
    self.tree.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES)
    self.tree.column('#0', stretch=tk.YES)
    self.tree.grid(row=5, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
    self.treeview = self.tree
    # Initialize the counter
    self.i = 1

    ttk.Label(self, text='Sum').grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='e') 
    ttk.Label(self,width = 10,).grid(row=6, column=2, sticky="e") #***I want to display the sume of values entered in the column 'Temp' in this label
def insert_data(self):

    self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=str(self.i), values=(self.entry.get(), self.entry1.get()+"h"))
    # Increment counter
    self.i = self.i + 1
```

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough detail. Usually we request that you create a [mcve] so that we can see what you've tried. Otherwise, the way your question is written it is simply too broad.

Comment: Sorry, I knew it was not clear but could not find a way to edit the posted question. However, my questions is :How can i add the values entered in a column of a treeview and display it in a label?

Comment: click on the [edit] button that is below the tags at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley Please check it now. If you are still unclear, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you want to calculate the total value inserted into `treeview` column. To do that you need to first get the content in the `treeview` using `tree.get_children()` then you iterate over it and use `index` to get the column you want to sum up the values.In my code is `index[0]`. This `sum1 +=` in my function means to add all the values in in the column.

You can change the index to [1] see the total value.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def my_values_cal():
    sum1 = 0.0
    for child in tree.get_children():
        sum1 += float(tree.item(child, "values")[0])
        lab.config(text=sum1)

        print(sum1)



root = tk.Tk()

tree =ttk.Treeview(root, column=("col1", "col2", "col3"), show="headings")
tree.heading('#1', text='Number')
tree.heading('#2', text='Temp')
tree.heading('#3', text='time')


tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(24, "09", "2:00 AM"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(34, "04", "5:00 AM"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(40, "09", "1:00 PM"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(94, "01", "23:00 PM"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("38", "21", "21:00 AM"))

tree.pack()

lab = tk.Label(root, text="Total")
lab.pack()


b = tk.Button(root, text="CALCULATE", command=my_values_cal)
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didnt knew about the 'get.children()' method. Good to know. Thank you again.

Comment: Extending to it, I am displaying numbers in the first column and entries in 2 & 3rd column. If i delete an entry from the treeview, how to automatically correct the numbers in first column? For eg. first column has entries 1,2,3,4,5 and if i delete th row '3', i am having 1,2,4,5 instead i need 1,2,3,4. So, how to automatically update the numbers? For displaying the numbers i just used a counter as you can see it in my main code above( def insert_data).

Comment: make a function that after deleting you insert the data left to the `treeview` again

Comment: No, however, I'm missing something there. my entry(row) deleting method is  
 ****def clear_one_data(self):                                                                                        
     selected_item = self.treeview.selection()[0] 
     self.treeview.delete(selected_item)        *******                                                           How do i insert the function that checks the other entries in the column and update the numbers automatically?

Comment: It will be hard for me without seeing the code, you can create minimal example and post new question.

Comment: Please have a look onto my new question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52145080/10285470)

Comment: have check the code but i can run to debug because it not enough to produce the error